# Wind- Powered phone charging bike rig

Tags: power

I have a 6V motor and another coming on the way. I am trying to create a phone charger on my bike using these motors with propeller blades. I will mount them on my bike and be able to ride and charge. My question is, How fast must I be going to make the motor spin?
[image]

Comment: Why not put a generator on the chain?

Comment: That's what I was thinking of doing, but I wanted it to be something I could take off and repair, or attach to another bike.

Comment: I think this is more a mechanical engineering question. You need to measure the blade pitch and use a vector diagram to calculate the blade velocity for a given wind velocity. From this you can calculate the RPM. There is also an equation for the max power you can extract given the blade swept area and forward velocity which would give you a good idea of whether it will work. I don't know it off the top off my head sorry.

Comment: I use a [hub dynamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hub_dynamo) and a couple super capacitors to power my lights and phone. Then you can take it off by removing the wheel. They're often rated for 6W, which will actually charge a phone, I doubt you'll get much from this. And it'll be intermittent, causing your display to turn on each time the power drops and it thinks it's been unplugged, which may actually end up wasting more energy.

Comment: @Samuel all my bicycles have hub dynamos and front lights that switch based on light and an output for the rear light, so I added a 32Wh LiFePO4 cell to the rear carrier that gets charged only when I cycle in daytime (LED headlight on one is 4W, but very very bright). Add a very low power circuit for load detection and I can charge my phone on any 40~90km trip, day or night.

Comment: @Asmyldof Very nice. Perhaps a schematic or links for the OP would be nice. With the input being either from a hub dynamo or spinning-cut-your-hands blades.

Comment: @Samuel they'll be very late. I'll need to draw up everything. Did it on impulse with nothing more than an idea and a lab full of parts.

Comment: How fast do you have to ride to make the motor spin? It depends on the motor, its friction, etc. How fast do you have to go to charge your phone from them? That has a very different answer! How much power does one of these motors take when run as a motor? At what speed does it turn the blades? Don't expect the same efficiency when run as a turbine and a generator. If you really want to go this route, consider a manifold to duct more air over your blades.

You'd do much better with a generator, or a solar charger.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search yields a nice paper showing the theoretical amount of power a wind turbine can produce, with wind speed, blade length, air density, and "Power conversion coefficient:"

http://www.raeng.org.uk/publications/other/23-wind-turbine

I'll make up some quick numbers: 10 centimeter long blades, USB charge power of 1 Amp at 5 Volts = 5 Watts, perfect electrical conversion to this voltage (ha!), very good turbine design and generator, so conversion coefficient of ~0.3, air density as given in the paper (1.23 kg/m^3)

P = 5 Watts = 0.5 * 1.23 * (pi/100) * V^3 * 0.3
or roughly 1000 = 1.23 * V^3
yielding V ~ 9.3 meters/second, or ~33 km/hour, or ~21 miles/hour. Keep that up for an hour or so without slowing down, and you might charge your phone.

Ducting more air over your blades would help, particularly as you're unlikely to get efficient conversion to 5V for your charger or the 0.3 power conversion coefficient.